# Create Hive Table on partionned by year month day parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, hdfs

I create a dataframe like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,27,"bob",2020,9,3),
  (1,27,"jack",2020,9,3),
  (3,31,"tom",2020,9,4)
).toDF("id","age","nom","year","month","day")
```

I get the following dataframe

```
+---+---+----+----+-----+---+
|id |age|nom |year|month|day|
+---+---+----+----+-----+---+
|1  |27 |bob |2020|9    |3  |
|1  |27 |jack|2020|9    |3  |
|3  |31 |tom |2020|9    |4  |
+---+---+----+----+-----+---+
```

then I write df on hdfs with partitionBy usig year, month day;

```
df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("year", "month", "day")
  .parquet(s"$outputPath/test_hive")
```

I get data on following hdfs paths:

- `/outputPath/test_hive/year=2020/month=9/day=3`
- `/outputPath/test_hive/year=2020/month=9/day=4`

I wonder how can I create an external hive table at location
`outputPath/test_hive` which could take into account subdirectories year, month and day.

I tried following create table but it does not works:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1(id int, age int, nom string, year int, month int, day int) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'outputPath/test_hive'

+-----------+------------+------------+--+
| test1.id  | test1.age  | test1.nom  |
+-----------+------------+------------+--+
| 1         | 27         | bob        |
| 1         | 27         | jack       |
| 3         | 31         | tom        |
+-----------+------------+------------+--+
```

and

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test2(id int, age int, nom string) PARTITIONED BY(year INT, month int , day INT) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'outputPath/test_hive'

+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+--+
| test2.id  | test2.age  | test2.nom  | test2.year  | test2.month  | test2.day  |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+--+
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+--------------+------------+--+
```

and

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test3(id int, age int, nom string) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'outputPath/test_hive' PARTITIONED BY(year INT, month int , day INT);

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:138 missing EOF at 'PARTITIONED' near ''/outputPath/test_hive'' (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Comment: what about change `stored as` and `partitioned by` order of the second one?

Comment: @Lamanus I tried to change order as you mentionned with the third one I just edited but i get an Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:138 missing EOF at 'PARTITIONED' near ''/outputPath/test_hive'' (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: what errors happen for the first two?

Comment: @Lamanus I get no error but i don't have expected data. I add to the question above results from hive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **`msck`** **`repair table or add partitions`** to the table.

**`Example:`**

**`From Hive:`**

```
hive> msck repair table test3

--or

hive> ALTER TABLE test3 ADD PARTITION (year='2020', month='9',day='3') location '/outputPath/test_hive/year=2020/month=9/day=3';
```

**`From spark:`**

```
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE test3 ADD PARTITION (year='2020', month='9',day='3') location '/outputPath/test_hive/year=2020/month=9/day=3'")

//or

spark.sql("msck repair table test3")
```

Comment: msck repair table test2 after each update of hdfs data do the job, Thank you